# Only getting data from the page which is open in the Browser

Tags: python, session, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

`
On Web
First Request Body:
eprocTenders:tenderNumber:
eprocTenders:tenderCategory: -1
eprocTenders:tenderTitle:
eprocTenders:tenderDescription:
eprocTenders:ecvRange: -1
eprocTenders:departmentId:
eprocTenders:status: EVALUATION_COMPLETED
eprocTenders:departmentLoc:
eprocTenders:tenderCreateDateFrom: 01/04/2019
eprocTenders:tenderCreateDateTo: 31/03/2020
eprocTenders:tenderSubmissionDateFrom:
eprocTenders:tenderSubmissionDateTo:
eprocTenders:selectTender: SEARCHTENDERS
eprocTenders:butSearch: Search
eprocTenders_SUBMIT: 1
jsf_sequence: 2
eprocTenders:dataScrollerId:
eprocTenders:*link_hidden*:

Second request body :

eprocTenders:tenderNumber:
eprocTenders:tenderCategory: -1
eprocTenders:tenderTitle:
eprocTenders:tenderDescription:
eprocTenders:ecvRange: -1
eprocTenders:departmentId:
eprocTenders:status: EVALUATION_COMPLETED
eprocTenders:departmentLoc:
eprocTenders:tenderCreateDateFrom: 01/04/2019
eprocTenders:tenderCreateDateTo: 31/03/2020
eprocTenders:tenderSubmissionDateFrom:
eprocTenders:tenderSubmissionDateTo:
eprocTenders:selectTender: SEARCHTENDERS
eprocTenders_SUBMIT: 1
jsf_sequence: 3
eprocTenders:dataScrollerId: idx2
eprocTenders:*link_hidden*: eprocTenders:dataScrollerIdidx2
`

**I am trying to scrape the data from this website:** [URL](https://eproc.karnataka.gov.in/eprocurement/common/eproc_tenders_list.seam)

This the code i am trying:

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

mydata = 'https://eproc.karnataka.gov.in/eprocurement/common/eproc_tenders_list.seam'

with requests.Session() as session:
   

     session.headers = {'Cookie':'JSESSIONID=DEBFA1809C30CE2F3F04D0044DFCA784.appp1vm22','Content-Type':'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryYxNGT6chlbwn3Ots','Content-Disposition': 'form-data', "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"}

   
    mydata_Text = []

    response = session.post(mydata , data=data ,verify =False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    for x in range(1,5):
        data = {
      
       
        'eprocTenders:status': 'EVALUATION_COMPLETED',
        'eprocTenders:tenderCreateDateFrom': '01/04/2019',
        'eprocTenders:tenderCreateDateTo': '31/03/2020',
        'eprocTenders:butSearch' : 'Search',
        'eprocTenders_SUBMIT': 1,
        'eprocTenders:dataScrollerId':'idx'+str(x),
     #         'eprocTenders:_link_hidden_: eprocTenders':'dataScrollerIdidx'+str(x),
        'jsf_sequence': str(x),
        'eprocTenders:selectTender': 'SEARCHTENDERS',
     
        }
        print(data)
        time.sleep(5)
        mycontent = soup.find('table', attrs={'id':'eprocTenders:browserTableEprocTenders'})
        table_body = mycontent.find('tbody')
        rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
        for row in rows:
            cols = row.find_all('td')
            cols = [me.text.strip() for me in cols]
            mydata_Text.append([me for me in cols if me])
            print(len(mydata_Text))
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You need to explain what is the problem with your code

Comment: problem is i am getting only data of the first page but mycode is working perfect and i can see the page its going on

Comment: you only get the first page because you never make another request after that. You keep creating a soup object from the same initial `response.content`

Answer (score 0):

you only get the first page because you never make another request after that. You keep creating a soup object from the same initial response.content. You'll need the request and parse within the loop. try something like:

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

mydata = 'https://eproc.karnataka.gov.in/eprocurement/common/eproc_tenders_list.seam'

with requests.Session() as session:
   

     session.headers = {'Cookie':'JSESSIONID=DEBFA1809C30CE2F3F04D0044DFCA784.appp1vm22','Content-Type':'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryYxNGT6chlbwn3Ots','Content-Disposition': 'form-data', "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"}

   
    mydata_Text = []

    #response = session.post(mydata , data=data ,verify =False) #<--- Put inside the loop
    #soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser') #<--- Put inside the loop
    for x in range(1,5):
        data = {
      
       
        'eprocTenders:status': 'EVALUATION_COMPLETED',
        'eprocTenders:tenderCreateDateFrom': '01/04/2019',
        'eprocTenders:tenderCreateDateTo': '31/03/2020',
        'eprocTenders:butSearch' : 'Search',
        'eprocTenders_SUBMIT': 1,
        'eprocTenders:dataScrollerId':'idx'+str(x),
     #         'eprocTenders:_link_hidden_: eprocTenders':'dataScrollerIdidx'+str(x),
        'jsf_sequence': str(x),
        'eprocTenders:selectTender': 'SEARCHTENDERS',
     
        }
        print(data)
        response = session.post(mydata , data=data ,verify =False) #< --- HERE
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser') #<--- HERE

        time.sleep(5)
        mycontent = soup.find('table', attrs={'id':'eprocTenders:browserTableEprocTenders'})
        table_body = mycontent.find('tbody')
        rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
        for row in rows:
            cols = row.find_all('td')
            cols = [me.text.strip() for me in cols]
            mydata_Text.append([me for me in cols if me])
            print(len(mydata_Text))
```

Comment: Its giving me same result repeating the same page result in my dataframe of size 80?? i am not getting what is the issue ?Please do take a look again- thanks in advance

Comment: chitown88 -I have tried this but its giving the same result ?

Comment: what is the parameter that returns the next page. That's what you'll need to iterate through. Unfortunately I can't  test because the site in not accessible for me to look at..

Comment: data = {
      
       
        'eprocTenders:status': 'EVALUATION_COMPLETED',
        'eprocTenders:tenderCreateDateFrom': '01/04/2019',
        'eprocTenders:tenderCreateDateTo': '31/03/2020',
        'eprocTenders:butSearch' : 'Search',
        'eprocTenders_SUBMIT': 1,
        'eprocTenders:dataScrollerId':'idx'+str(x),
     #         'eprocTenders:_link_hidden_: eprocTenders':'dataScrollerIdidx'+str(x),
        'jsf_sequence': str(x),
        'eprocTenders:selectTender': 'SEARCHTENDERS',
     
        }

this portion have   'eprocTenders:dataScrollerId':'idx'+str(x),

Comment: hmmm. try changing to `response =  session.post(mydata , params=data ,verify =False) ` and you are sure it's a POST not a GET, correct?

Comment: yes its POST method , is it possible with beautifulsoup because i am loosing hope here :(

Comment: I don't think it's an issue with beautifulsoup. It has something to do with what's getting returned in the request, I believe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220493/discussion-between-quicklearner-gk-and-chitown88).

Comment: Please help ? i am fedup with this not getting anyidea

Comment: there was issue with sessionid - its done - i solved it